# Finding what memory I am allocation

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I am making an Android game and of course I refrain from allocating memory during game-play.

However I am pretty sure I am not allocating any memory, and have covered the code extensively looking for memory allocations. I have not found any.

But when I run my game on my phone I see it's a little jumpy for the first round, and when I look at the Catlog I see that the GC is running pretty often. The GC runs about once every 3 seconds. After the first round of the game. The GC runs about once per 10 seconds.

Is there a way other then looking at code to see what is being allocated? This is an Android game but I am able to run it on the PC as well (Libgdx), so I can use both Android specific solutions and java solutions.

Comment: Have you used ddms's memory allocation profiling?

Comment: Do you mean the traceview thingy? If so then I will try it out soon - But last time I used It I found it very not user friendly and had trouble with it.

Comment: Not traceview as in log cat, if you're using eclipse with ADT try the ddms perspective.

Comment: Hmm I was unaware of that tool - it's pretty good. But is there a way to limit it to heap allocations only?

Comment: I don't know of any way to limit to heap allocations.